# Turn wifi/bluetooth off permanently in the Control Center - not until tomorrow

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, control-center

I'm new to the iPhone. I wonder how I can turn wifi or bluetooth off permanently in the Control Center. When I press the button, it says that wifi is turned off until tomorrow, whatever that means.

For some people this may work, but not for me. I almost never use wifi, and if I turn it on and then turn it off, I don't want to go into the settings to handle it there. Is there a setting I'm missing that can change this behavior? Same goes for Bluetooth.

Comment: It’s designed so that WiFi and Bluetooth are always on. This simplifies the experience, so that things “just work”. What’s your concern with having them on?

Comment: You can long press the icon twice, which will give you a direct link to the relevant settings btw.

Comment: I'm fine with this "design", if I could change it somewhere deep in the settings to have it work like I want it. Long pressing would be great but doesn't open the settings. It opens a bigger popup, not the actual settings. Why do I want this? I want control and easy access. I would expect in the settings a button to change this behavior.

Comment: Long press once to open the bigger pop up, long press again to open the modal, then tap “Settings…” on the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Turning off WiFi in Control Center is a temporary toggle. Apple intended it to be that, way. Why? your guess is as good as mine.

If you want WiFi off go into

`Settings > Wi-Fi`

And toggle the green switch at the top to off. It will stay that way. Only control center turns it off temporarily.